# Login and Authentication in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to create a login function and login authentication in the views.py inside `def login(request)` for particular username and password from my model class "Signup" . Could someone please help me in my existing code how to do so or share any resources to perform the following operation.

P.S. I am new to Django and getting overwhelmed by the information present in the internet due which couldn't get the solution to my problem.

I am adding my code snippets for `models.py` , `views.py` , `urls.py` and `login.html` .

"models.py"

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class SignUp(models.Model):
    username= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    address=models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

"views.py"

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import SignUp
from django.contrib.auth import login,authenticate,logout

# Create your views here.

def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username= request.POST['username']
        password= request.POST['password']

        user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)
        html2 = "<html><body>No such user</body></html>"

        if user is not None:
            login(request,user)
            return redirect('')
        else:
            return HttpResponse(html2)
    else:

        return render(request,'login.html')

def signup(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username= request.POST['username']
        email= request.POST['email']
        password1= request.POST['password1']
        password2= request.POST['password2']
        address= request.POST['address']
        html = "<html><body>Confirm Password and Password should be same </body></html>"
        html1= "<html><body>User Already present </body></html>"

        if password1 != password2:
            return HttpResponse(html)
        else:
            for instance in SignUp.objects.all():
                if (instance.username == username) or (instance.email==email):
                    return HttpResponse(html1)
            signup=SignUp(username=username,email=email,password=password1,address=address)
            signup.save()

            return redirect('login')

    else:

        return render(request,'signup.html')
```

"urls.py"

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.signup, name='signup'),
    path('signup/',views.signup,name='signup'),
    path('login/',views.login,name='login'),

]
```

"login.html"

```
<!--
Author: Colorlib
Author URL: https://colorlib.com
License: Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 Unported
License URL: http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/
-->
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Form</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="application/x-javascript"> addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false); function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); } </script>
<!-- Custom Theme files -->
<link href="{% static 'styles/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<!-- //Custom Theme files -->
<!-- web font -->
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- //web font -->
</head>
<body>
    <!-- main -->
    <div class="main-w3layouts wrapper">
        <h1>LOGIN</h1>
        <div class="main-agileinfo">
            <div class="agileits-top">
                <form action="/login/" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input class="text" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required="">
                    <input class="text" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required="">
        

                    <input type="submit" value="LOGIN">
                </form>
                <!-- <p>Don't have an Account? <a href="#"> Login Now!</a></p> -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- copyright -->
        <!-- <div class="colorlibcopy-agile">
            <p>© 2018 Colorlib Signup Form. All rights reserved | Design by <a href="https://colorlib.com/" target="_blank">Colorlib</a></p>
        </div> -->
        <!-- //copyright -->
        <ul class="colorlib-bubbles">
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- //main -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You do not need to worry about the SignUp model. Django does it for you. Django has built in User model which is used for authentication and storing Users' data like: username, email, password, first_name, last_name and so on. You just need to know how to use the django User model to signup user and authenticate. you can check this link https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/series/2017/09/25/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-django-part-4.html

Answer (score 0):

okay i agree with yuv,

What you want to do is basically replace this

```
class SignUp(models.Model):
    username= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    address=models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
 """
 add the required fields that you need apart from django's builtin 
 user model
 """
 address = models.Textfield(_("address"))
```

Now this can help fulfil the requirement of model and you will be able use the authenticate method on fields such as username and email with password that you store during signup using set_password function to hash the password and store it in your db which can be used securely afterwords.